# Encrypted HLS not playing in iPad 2

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, drm, ipad-2

I have generated HLS content using ffmpeg. This content is plain (i.e. without encryption).
I am doing the segment level encryption i.e. after ffmpeg gives out the *.ts segments then
I encrypt them using AES-128, CBC mode.
After encrypting the content I edit the media playlist file.
Following is the url of the encrypted HLS content I mentioned above.

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hls-content/out_s3.m3u8

This content is not playing on iPad 2. What could be the possible problem with this content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the key file,The key has been specified in hex instead of that now it should be written as ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your #EXT-X-KEY tag is nonconformant. It must be only 1 line (not using \ and continuing on the next line).

In the specification document, the \ is shown only as an aid to reading, but it's not actually  allowed. From [section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-12#section-3.1):

> An M3U Playlist is a text file that consists of individual lines.
> Lines are terminated by either a single LF character or a CR character
> followed by an LF character.  Each line is a URI, blank, or starts
> with the character '#'.  Blank lines are ignored.  White space MUST
> NOT be present, except for elements in which it is explicitly
> specified.

Comment: \ is basically an escape character, it essentially means that the IV is in the same line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess I have figured out the problem, it was in the key file.